# Playing *.au files on Linux via HTML object

Tags: html, linux

Is it possible to make this code to work on Linux?

```
<object height="50" width="200" data="some_file.au"></object>
```

That opened an audio window to my browser on Windows XP, but not anymore at Ubuntu Linux.

AFAIK `*.au` files are not that Windows specific, so what may be the problem in here?

I have that web page run at same `file://somePathToFiles` path and the files are at same path than the `html` file itself.

More complete web page example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>

   <body>
      <object height="50" width="200" data="computer.au"></object>
      <object height="50" width="200" data="gong.au"></object>
      <object height="50" width="200" data="drip.au"></object>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

It turned out I did not have any media player installed on my semi-fresh Linux installation.

I took one with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer gecko-mediaplayer
```

..and now that new player was opened, when I reloaded the page *(Actually three times, I had three files)*. Player was rendered to the web page, not in own window. Just like I wanted.

**Lessons learned:**

This Object thing on html uses embedded native player and in the lack of one, of course nothing happened.

**Source:**

[1] http://www.ehow.com/info_12229443_firefox-plugin-problems-media-player-ubuntu.html